# recording streaming audio with huge periods of silence

Tags: audio, audio-streaming, audio-recording, icecast, audacity

I'm using darkice (http://darkice.org) on a Linux box to capture an audio feed from a fire department radio system. It works great and I can forward the stream to an Icecast2 (https://icecast.org) server so the firefighters can listen to live radio transmissions.

My next goal is to actually record radio transmissions to file.

The fire department isn't always that busy, so the stream I'm capturing has huge periods of silence (hiss).  My goal is to somehow capture and record to file only the periods where there are real, human voice transmissions and not waste huge amounts of hard disk space recording hiss.

Any thoughts on the tools that might be able to conquer this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use FFmpeg for this, and its [`silenceremove` filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#silenceremove).

Untested, but try something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i <Icecast URL> -af silenceremove=stop_periods=-1:stop_duration=1:stop_threshold=-30dB output.webm
```

Comment: I've been testing this today and it seems to be working well so far.  Since my posting I've also discovered 'sox', which I'll be trying too.  Thanks.